# inQuiescent Current with Downsteam Devices

Tags: current, quiescent

I have a circuit with a regulator (TI TPS61098 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=tps61098&fileType=pdf)) with 300nA
Ultra-Low Iq in "low power mode". What is the total current draw if I have other downstream devices with leakage current when the system is in "low power mode"? Let's say my input voltage is 1V and output is 3.3V.

Will the TI regulator only draw 300nA from the input rail or I_input  = 300nA + (Downstream Leakage Current x Efficiency x 3.3/1) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the TPS61098 is in "Low Power Mode" and drawing only 300nA of quiescent current, there will not be an output voltage on your Vout rail. If you look at the datasheet, it shows "No load, No Switching", meaning that your Vout will not be supplying any voltage. Therefore, you shouldn't be seeing any leakage current downstream since there's no current to draw to bein with.

[image]